# Ember.js: How to inject dependency into adapter?

Tags: ember.js, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject some global application configuration (or state or options) into all components such as routes, controller and data adapter.
Dont know why this code dont inject dependency into data adapter. Maybe problem is in ordering?

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
    LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
});

var RESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

    primaryKey: '_id',

    buildURL: function() {
        var locale = this.get('options.locale');
        return locale + this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});

App.ApplicationStore = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: RESTAdapter
});

App.initializer({

    name: 'options',

    initialize: function(container, app) {
        var o = Ember.Object.create();
        o.set('default-locale', 'en');
        app.register('globals:options', o, { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
    }

});

App.initializer({

    name: 'injectOptions',
    before: 'options',

    initialize: function(container, app) {
        app.inject('controller', 'options', 'globals:options'); // OK
        app.inject('route', 'options', 'globals:options'); // OK
        app.inject('data-adapter', 'options', 'globals:options'); // not working
        app.inject('dataAdapter', 'options', 'globals:options'); // not working
        app.inject('adapter', 'options', 'globals:options'); // not working
        app.inject('store', 'options', 'globals:options'); // ???
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Injection is done on creation, it's likely the store and adapter's are probably just being created before the injection takes place.  Just set your initializer to go before `ember-data`.

```
App.initializer({
  before:'ember-data',
    name: 'options',

    initialize: function(container, app) {
        var o = Ember.Object.create();
        o.set('default-locale', 'en');
        app.register('globals:options', o, { instantiate: false, singleton: true });
    }

});

App.initializer({

    name: 'injectOptions',
    before: 'options',

    initialize: function(container, app) {
        app.inject('controller', 'options', 'globals:options'); // OK
        app.inject('route', 'options', 'globals:options'); // OK
        app.inject('data-adapter', 'options', 'globals:options'); // not working
        app.inject('dataAdapter', 'options', 'globals:options'); // not working
        app.inject('adapter', 'options', 'globals:options'); // not working
        app.inject('store', 'options', 'globals:options'); // ???
    }

});
```

Example: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1012/edit

Additionally declaring the store is a deprecated pattern.  You should just declare adapters:

```
var RESTAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

    primaryKey: '_id',

    buildURL: function() {
        var locale = this.get('options.locale');
        return locale + this._super.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});

App.ApplicationAdapter = RESTAdapter;
```